# iOS Application - How To Check Server For Updates Every 60 Seconds?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, background

I'm currently developing an application that needs to constantly check the server it's associated with every 60 seconds for any updates that may have occured. The server side of it is fine and not a problem.

My issue is how do I implement a process in xcode which starts when the application is launched and continues to run even when the user navigates away from the application (Presses the home button, for example)? I believe the proper solution here is background tasks? What would be the correct way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, only apps that meet a certain criteria can run in the background for an extended period of time - For instance, Audio, VoIP, location etc.  So if your app does not meet this criteria, then you cannot run in the BG for an extended period.  There have been some workarounds suggested like declaring your app as needing audio and then playing a silent sound in the background but that may not go through the App Store and the app may be required to prompt the user if it can play the audio. **Besides, the constant polling will be a battery drain** and I would not recommend it.

Have you instead considered the use of [Apple PUSH Notifications](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAD&url=http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12&ei=WzyfUcjhNsjLyQGusoBA&usg=AFQjCNHfz2hugeeo6_bxN-rN-60WQr3K7A&sig2=a0fGrOL4BQkKNtmuUCVXrg&bvm=bv.47008514,d.aWc) in order to be notified of any updates? 
Refer [backgrounding support in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)